# What to try if Remote Desktop login sometimes results in a black screen?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I've tried a number of "solutions" that have not worked for me.
I determined that shutting down my computer and logging back in worked.

I've experimented a bit and determined that if I run the Services control panel (with Admin rights) and I Stop/Start cycle the Remote Desktop Configuration service, voila, I can log in and not have that black screen!

Sure beats rebooting the client computer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Community BOT. What is a person supposed to do when one finds a solution to a problem others have tried to address but solutions offered didn't work? There's a question for the thread...